# Log4j doesn't work in test classes

Tags: java, logging, junit, log4j, gradle

i have a source folder for selenium testing: **src/selenium/java**
and i have unit test class under it, and the implementation is as follows:

```
package com.myapp.selenium;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class HomeTest {

    static WebDriver driver;
    protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeTest.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
            logger.info("Running Selenium Test for class"+HomeTest.class.getSimpleName());
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void after() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void addingOneUser() throws InterruptedException {
        if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
            logger.info("addingOneUser");
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.xhtml");  
    }

}
```

**log4j.properties**:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F%L) - %m%n  

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=application.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.myapp=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug
```

and **log4j jars**:

```
'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2'
'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.2'
'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.2'
```

**UPDATE:**

my **gradle.build**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
//apply from:'http://github.com/breskeby/gradleplugins/raw/master/emmaPlugin/emma.gradle'
apply from: 'emma.gradle'
buildDir = 'build'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = ''

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:0.6'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo url: 'http://repository.primefaces.org'
    mavenRepo url: 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public'
    mavenRepo url: 'http://repository.jboss.org/maven2'
    mavenRepo url: 'http://maven.springframework.org/release'
    mavenRepo url: 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
    mavenRepo url: 'http://git.solutionstream.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty'
}


configurations {
   compileOnly
   weldEmbeddedTestRuntime { extendsFrom testRuntime }
   jbossasRemoteTestRuntime { extendsFrom testRuntime, compileOnly }
}

sourceSets {

   main {
      compileClasspath = configurations.compile + configurations.compileOnly
   }

   test {
      compileClasspath = compileClasspath + configurations.compileOnly
   }

   selenium {
      compileClasspath = compileClasspath + configurations.compileOnly
   }
}

dependencies {
    //JSF
    compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-api', version: '2.1.22'
    compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-impl', version: '2.1.22'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.rewrite:rewrite-servlet:2.0.3.Final'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.rewrite:rewrite-config-prettyfaces:2.0.3.Final'


    //Servlet
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    providedCompile group: 'org.jboss.spec', name: 'jboss-javaee-6.0', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    compile 'taglibs:standard:1.1.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '3.2.2.RELEASE'

    //Omnifaces
    compile 'org.omnifaces:omnifaces:1.5'

    //Prime Faces
    compile group: 'org.primefaces', name: 'primefaces', version: '4.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.primefaces.themes:bootstrap:1.0.10'

    // DB
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.3.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '3.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.9'

    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    compile group: 'javax.enterprise', name: 'cdi-api', version: '1.0-SP4'
    compile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2'

    //Hibernate / JPA   
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.0.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.1.0.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final'
    //JSR-303
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.1.Final'

    // Spring Security
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.4.RELEASE'

    //Utility
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.typesafe:config:1.0.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile 'org.apache.geronimo.javamail:geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail:1.8.3'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.2'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.2'


    //Mustache Templates
    compile 'com.github.jknack:handlebars:1.0.0'

    //Projects
    //compile project(":ExtraValidators")

    ////TESTING DEPENDENCIES
    testCompile 'com.googlecode.jmockit:jmockit:1.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.172'

    //Spring Testing
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.3.RELEASE'

    /* Selenium */
    seleniumCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.33.0'
    seleniumCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    seleniumCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2'
    seleniumCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.2'
    seleniumCompile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.2'

    /* Remote Jboss */
    testCompile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian', name: 'arquillian-junit', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'   
    jbossasRemoteTestRuntime group: 'org.jboss.arquillian.container', name: 'arquillian-jbossas-remote-6', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    jbossasRemoteTestRuntime group: 'org.jboss.jbossas', name: 'jboss-as-server', classifier: 'client', version: '6.1.0.Final', transitive: false
    jbossasRemoteTestRuntime group: 'org.jboss.jbossas', name: 'jboss-as-profileservice', classifier: 'client', version: '6.1.0.Final'
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
    gradleVersion = '1.6'
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
       downloadSources=true
       plusConfigurations += configurations.seleniumCompile
    }
}


task selenium(type: Test) {
   testClassesDir = sourceSets.selenium.output.classesDir
   classpath = sourceSets.selenium.runtimeClasspath  + files('src/selenium/resources-jbossas') + configurations.jbossasRemoteTestRuntime
}
```

and i run the selenium test from command line with **gradlew selenium**.

please advise why logging doesn't work either on debug or info.

Comment: Where is your `log4j.properties` located?

Comment: @Buhake Sindi, i added gradle configuration.

Comment: That still doesn't tell us where the `log4j.properties` file is located within your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple possible reasons:

- your `log4j.properties` is not on the classpath. Print out the classpath to be sure, the directory your log4j.properties is in appears there. If log4j doesn't find any configuration you should see a warning about that in the console.
- some other `log4j.properties` is used. See the default initialization proceedure [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for information which files might get considered. Since log4j most probably uses the class loader to find the configuration file, it should be possible to configure java so it logs everything the classloader loads. This will be a lot of stuff, but it should also contain the log4j.properties file use. Or you search log4j source code for the "log4j.properties", use this to find the place where the configuration gets loaded and use a debugger to find what exactly gets loaded.

Comment: i added gradle configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to `build.gradle`:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j.properties"]

test {
    jvmArgs "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j.properties"
}
```

My `log4j.properties` file is located in `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the project. I solved problem this way.